Multiple column pivot/transpose using R dataframes
I have this dataframe:
my_df = tibble("name_1"= c("year", "month", "toyota", "hyundai"), 
       "name_2" = c("year", "month", "auris", "iconiq"), 
       "unk_1" = c(2020, 'Jan', 100, 150),
       "unk_2" = c(2020, 'feb', 200, 400))

How can i transpose two columns - or using a pivot_longer() to get the following dataframe:
new_df = tibble("car_name" = c("toyota", "hyundai"), 
       "model" = c("auris", "iconiq"), 
       "year" = c(2020, 2020), 
        'month' = c("Jan", "Feb"), 
        'list_price' = c(100, 150), 
       "sell_price" = c(200, 400))

the pivot or transpose should include both the month and year rows effectively.
I have tried data.table and pivot_longer() but still stuck.

This question is ill-defined. How can you tell that toyota is January and hyundai is February from the original dataset?

With data.table::transpose
setNames(
  cbind(my_df[3:4, 1:2], data.table::transpose(my_df[,3:4])),
  c("car_name", "model", "year", "month", "list_price", "sell_price")
)
#>   car_name  model year month list_price sell_price
#> 3   toyota  auris 2020   Jan        100        150
#> 4  hyundai iconiq 2020   feb        200        400


The question is ill-defined. This is forceful coercion.  From the data, it is unclear how hyundai is related to with february while toyota is related to january

it's supposed to be rows are related in the order they arrive in - there is no need for further cleaning

I was scratching my head a bit on how the OP could get data structured as it is in the question. How would my_df look if it contained three vehicles instead of two? It would presumably have another row, but where would the month/year for the third vehicle go?

Maybe it has lots more columns for every observed month, most of which are blank/zero?
